# Query to join two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am a newbie in MYSQL. Any help on this will be appreciated.

I have two tables Airports  and Posts with the following Fields:

**Airports**

```
id, Airport-code, Airport_name
```

**Posts**

```
id, Source_Airport_code, Destination_airport_code, Date_of_departure, preference
```

How do I get a record with the following fields (Here Source and Destination corresponds to Airport names instead of the codes):

```
Source, destination, date_of_departure
```

Answer (score 2):

If the FK in `Posts.*_Airport_code` doesn't refer to `Airports.id` as MJB assumes but to `Airports.Airport_code` then

```
SELECT
  APS.Airport_name AS Source,
  APD.Airport_name AS Destination,
  Posts.date_of_departure
FROM Posts
  INNER JOIN Airports APS ON(APS.Airport_code = Posts.Source_Airport_code)
  INNER JOIN Airports APD ON(APD.Airport_code = Posts.Destination_airport_code)
```

Comment: D'oh -- I think you are right. I should have read more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to start:

```
select 
  s.airport_name as source, 
  d.airport_name as destination, 
  p.date_of_departure
from posts p
  inner join airports s
    on p.source_airport_code = s.id
  inner join airports d
    on d.source_airport_code = d.id
```

And I hate to say it, but I think you have a long way to go.